# Java Sorting a List whilst ignoring a apostrophe

Tags: java, sorting, csv

I have a list that I am sorting which is reading from a CSV file.

Now when i sort the code I get:
[image]

But if I sort the CSV file on Excel it's slightly different
[image]

So technically Excel is ignoring the case of Apostrophe but mine isn't. The criteria doesn't specify what to do in this case, but I would assume my code is incorrect then. How would i ignore the case of the Apostrophe and go onto the next character?

My code is:

```
public static Comparator<Hill> compareName = new Comparator<Hill>() {
    public int compare(Hill one, Hill other) {
        return one.name.compareTo(other.name);
    }
};

public static void exercise5d() {
    List<Hill> hills = readHills();
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        Collections.sort(hills, Hill.compareName);
        System.out.println(hills.get(i));
    }

}
```

Comment: The Java code is doing exactly what you told it to do, and you told it to do something different from what Excel does. The thing to do is figure out what Excel used to compare two elements, and include that logic in your code, which so far you didn't do. If Excel needs to ignore apostrophes, don't expect code that does not ignore them to match. Write your code to ignore them also, along the lines of @VHS's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your comparator,

replace

`return one.name.compareTo(other.name);`

with

`return one.name.replaceAll("'","").compareTo(other.name.replaceAll("'",""));`

Comment: Not quite, although it fixed it for the first entry i had, where the apostrophe was at the start, it's still printing the ones where the apostrophe was after the A

Comment: Additionally, you probably also want `compareToIgnoreCase`

Comment: @godlypython, you might want to show your `Hill` class in that case.

Comment: @AJNeufeld, no you don't want to ignore the case while sorting strings.

Comment: While this code solves the problem, it's also exceedingly CPU- and garbage-intensive. At the very least, consider using `replace` instead of `replaceAll`. Depending on the size of your list, you may be better off writing a custom comparator that compares two strings character by character, ignoring the `'` and upcasing the chars. Ultimately, you may need to pre-process the list.

Comment: @VHS According to the Excel sort, Abbey Hill < A'Bheinn < Abney Low, so yes, case is being ignored.

Comment: @Arkadiy, explain why or how it is cpu intensive or "garbage-intensive". How will comparing your way (character by character) be better from performance point of view? Why `replace` and not `replaceAll`?

Comment: @AJNeufeld, I see. I will let OP take the call on whether he / she wants to ignore the case or not.

Comment: replaceAll "Replaces each substring of this string that matches the given regular expression with the given replacement.". That means for every comparison you (twice) invoke Pattern.compile(), create a Pattern and a Match and a new String (and possibly a String builder somehere in there too). replace() is more old-fashioned, it just scans the string for characters. And simply scannig the string avoids all of it.

Comment: Well, now both options work, just a matter of decision on which is the sensible thing to do

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming `Hill.name` is a `String`.

In your comparator you could compare `String`s after replacing apostrophes like below :

```
public int compare(Hill one, Hill other) {

        return one.name.replaceAll("'", "").compareTo(other.name.replaceAll("'","");
    }
```

But do you think you don't want to consider `'` ?

Comment: Well that's what im not entirely sure about since Im getting two different results of sorting from Java and excel. Cuz lets say i have an entry "Abberley". That isn't in the list because A'bhain is showing up.